# Merging multiple sheets into one master sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have one client form for 12 people. All 12 have the same exact form. I am creating a "Master" Client form.  All the sheets are EXACTLY alike.  I need to pull everyone's information onto the new Master sheet.  And the master has to be searchable.

It would be super helpful if it counted every duplicate, deleted the extra ones and kept the one with the oldest date. The date is in Column A. So I can see how many times a client called and the first date they called.

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fAWp27XX30VK-NLeJ6QwE8dzcqJOqdTyil4RKUWG7aY/).

Answer (score 2):

You could have a tab and do

```
 =IMPORTRANGE("abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10")
 //IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key, range_string)
```

and do that until you get all twelve sheet and the on your other sheet

just use

```
  =ARRAYFORMULA({Sheet1!"A3:A19";Sheet2!"B3:B19"})
```

and add whatever filter you want with it., even create a pivot table.